# Can not connect to java SFTP server running on localhost Mac OS v10.15.5

Tags: java, macos, server, connection, sftp

I have started java sftp server using following code:

Here is maven dependencies:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
            <artifactId>mina-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.sshd</groupId>
            <artifactId>sshd-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Here is source code:

```
import org.apache.sshd.server.SshServer;
import org.apache.sshd.server.keyprovider.SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider;
import org.apache.sshd.server.subsystem.sftp.SftpSubsystemFactory;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SshServer sshd = SshServer.setUpDefaultServer();
        sshd.setPort(22);
        sshd.setKeyPairProvider(new SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider(new File("host.ser").toPath()));
        sshd.setSubsystemFactories(Collections.singletonList(new SftpSubsystemFactory()));
        sshd.setPasswordAuthenticator((username, password, session) -> username.equals("test") && password.equals("password"));
        sshd.start();
    }
}
```

Then I go to the terminal of the same machine and try to connect to the running sftp server:

```
sftp test@127.0.0.1
```

**But nothing happen. Connection just waiting.**

I also tried following command :

```
sftp test@localhost
```

At the same time when I try to telnet to the port 22 I am getting following:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Answer (score -1):

`ssh-keygen -R 127.0.0.1` solved my problem

Comment: This makes little sense. `ssh-keygen` cannot have any impact on *"telnet to the port 22"*.

Comment: I mean after ssh-keygen I was able to "sftp test@127.0.0.1"

Comment: If you cannot even connect to the port, `ssh-keygen` cannot help.